# Lua oop - timer implementation

Tags: oop, lua, coronasdk

I was following this tutorial http://www.crawlspacegames.com/blog/inheritance-in-lua/ and created 2 objects (drums and Guitar) that inherit from MusicalInstrument. Everything worked fine until I added timer functions, then for some reason only 1 from the 2 objects that inherit from MusicalInstrument gets called

MusicalInstrument.lua:

```
module(...,package.seeall)

MusicalInstrument.type="undefined"

local function listener()
print("timer action: "..MusicalInstrument.type)
end

function MusicalInstrument:play(tpe)
    MusicalInstrument.type = tpe;
    print("play called by: "..MusicalInstrument.type)
    timer.performWithDelay(500,listener,3)
end

function MusicalInstrument:new( o )
    x = x or {} -- can be parameterized, defaults to a new table
    setmetatable(x, self)
    self.__index = self
    return x
end
```

Guitar.lua

```
module(...,package.seeall)
require("MusicalInstrument")

gtr = {}

setmetatable(gtr, {__index = MusicalInstrument:new()})

return gtr
```

Drums.lua

```
module(...,package.seeall)
require("MusicalInstrument")

drms = {}

setmetatable(drms, {__index = MusicalInstrument:new()})

return drms
```

main.lua

```
--    CLEAR TERMINAL    --
os.execute('clear')
print( "clear" ) 
--------------------------


local drms=require("Drums")

drms:play("Drums")

local gtr=require("Guitar")

gtr:play("Guitar")
```

This is the terminal output:

```
clear
play called by: Drums
play called by: Guitar
timer action: Guitar
timer action: Guitar
timer action: Guitar
timer action: Guitar
timer action: Guitar
timer action: Guitar
```

I excepted the output to have 3 guitar time calls and 3 drums timer calls

Any ideas on how to make this work will be appreciated much!!

Thanks

----------------------------- Edited after another try -------------------

The following change in MusicalInstrument

```
module(...,package.seeall)

MusicalInstrument.type="undefined"

function MusicalInstrument:listener()
print("timer action: "..MusicalInstrument.type)
end

function MusicalInstrument:play(tpe)
    MusicalInstrument.type = tpe;
    print("play called by: "..MusicalInstrument.type)
    timer.performWithDelay(500,MusicalInstrument:listener(),3)
end

function MusicalInstrument:new( o )
    x = x or {} -- can be parameterized, defaults to a new table
    setmetatable(x, self)
    self.__index = self
    return x
end
```

Resulted with the following output :

```
clear
play called by: Drums
timer action: Drums
play called by: Guitar
timer action: Guitar
```

The correct instruments were called by the timer but only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both `listener` and `MusicalInstrument:play()` you write and read the same variable for both instances.

You actually want to set the instrument type per instance here. Lua is not exactly my primary language, but e.g. something like:

```
function MusicalInstrument:listener()
    print("timer action: "..self.type)
end

function MusicalInstrument:play(tpe)
    self.type = tpe;
    local f = function() self:listener() end
    timer.performWithDelay(500, f, 3)
end
```

Comment: you rock!      @#@     1234567890

Comment: any lua resources you recommend??

Comment: @Eran: I only read a bit through the [Lua docs](http://www.lua.org/docs.html) when needed. But then again i only fiddle a bit with an existing Lua code base for a mod.